# owncloud regeneration of database's tables

Tags: database, owncloud

I happen to be interested by the PHP syncing software [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/). I set it up quite correctly, except for the database, that I had to create after I had installed ownCloud for some obscure reasons.

As a result, the database is empty. I believe this is not going to help for syncing and versioning.

**Issue:**
I cannot find the way to regenerate manually the tables of the database, that is, a script to run that would take my new database and put into it the brand new tables ready to be used. Would anyone have an idea on how to accomplish that?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Delete the installation and start over, this time allowing it to populate the database. Another option: It's quite likely there is an `.sql` file somewhere in the owncloud directory that contains the initial database content.

Answer (score 5):

Go to /config folder and rename config.php to config.php.backup.
Goto your owncloud and the install will appear again.
Also, you might want to redownload ownCloud since version 7 comes out tomorrow.